# How to insert web part above all existing web parts

Tags: development, csom

I need to add a web part to the **TOP OF THE PAGE**. I tried this code:

```
var sp = new SPClient("https://domain.sharepoint.com/path/to/site");
sp.InsertScriptEditor(
    "default.aspx",
    "top",
    0,
    $"Welcome script editor web part",
    $"&lt;h1 style=&quot;color:red;&quot;&gt;CONFIDENTIAL&lt;/h1&gt;");
```

Where

```
public void InsertScriptEditor(string pagePath, string zoneId,
    int zoneIndex, string description, string content)
{
    var webPartXml = string.Format(WebParts.ScriptEditorXml, description, content);

    using (var clientContext = new ClientContext(baseUrl))
    {
        InsertWebPart(clientContext, webPartXml, pagePath,
            zoneId, zoneIndex, description, content);
    }
}
```

and

```
private void InsertWebPart(ClientContext clientContext, string webPartXml, 
    string pagePath, string zoneId, int zoneIndex, string description, string content)
{
    var relUrl = new Uri(baseUrl).AbsolutePath;

    clientContext.Credentials = credentials;
    var web = clientContext.Web;

    var page = clientContext.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl($"{relUrl}/{pagePath}");
    var webPartManager = page.GetLimitedWebPartManager(PersonalizationScope.Shared);

    var importedWebPart = webPartManager.ImportWebPart(webPartXml);
    var webPart = webPartManager.AddWebPart(importedWebPart.WebPart, zoneId, zoneIndex);
    clientContext.Load(webPart);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

But it always appears below some existing web parts in the template.

I tried setting `zoneId` to -1, but I got some error about it being an invalid value.

How can I just put it above all other web parts? Surely that is possible?

Comment: try zone Id of 1. I once had a similar issue: http://www.sharepointnadeem.com/2014/10/sharepoint-web-parts-not-adding-in.html

Comment: @NadeemYousuf It still doesn't seem to consistently add it to the top, how annoying!